# how i can populate a Gridview combobox with a list of user defined object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

in EF i have a Entity,Stuff and i wanna populate a Gridview combobox with all Stuff in Stuffs table with this code:

```
 var stuffs = from t in Database.Context.Stuffs
              select t;
 return stuffs.ToList<Stuff>();

 datagridview.datasource=stuffs;
```

i override ToString Method:

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
    return this.Name + "-" + this.CompanyName;
 }
```

but Get this error:

datagridview combobox cell value not valid error

Comment: after assigning a Datasource where are you Binding the data..?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have a combobox showing multiple columns?

Can you send the xaml code of your combo box and how do you bind it?

If so, what you probably need is to bind each column on a property of your class, instead of overriding ToString() to returns each value in a string.

Comment: no,when i write datagridviewcombobox.datasource=list<Stuff>,compiler look for override ToString() for Show in combobox

Comment: <GridViewComboBoxColumn                                        Header="Type Of Stuff" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static ListOfStuff}}" 
DataMemberBinding="{Binding TypeOfStuff}"/>

Comment: You probably have a DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValueMemberPath property that you need to set to tell your combo box which is the Value and What you want to show as item text

Comment: i wanna Show Name+"-"+Companyname,in comboxbox,that is work fine in combobox but no work in datagridviewcombobox

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the best way to do it, I'm not familiar with WinForms.

But with this sample, it seems to do want you want :
[image]

```
class Stuff
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CieName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Name, CieName);
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Stuff> _myList = new List<Stuff>()
                                          {
                                              new Stuff() {Name = "Anne", CieName = "Google"},
                                              new Stuff() {Name = "Creg", CieName = "Yahoo"}
                                          };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindComboBoxColumnDataSource();
        }

        private void BindComboBoxColumnDataSource()
        {
            var comboColumn = dataGridView1.Columns["ComboBoxColumn"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;

            if (comboColumn != null)
                comboColumn.DataSource = _myList;
        }
    }
```